# How to configure multiple nics / ips on Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: linux-networking, ubuntu-14.04

I have a virtual machine running Ubuntu 14.04 running on some VMWare visualization framework. The machine is configured with multiple nics which are connected to two groups of IP addresses (each group is a 255.255.255.248 mask subnet).

I'm trying to configure the network interfaces in such a way that all IPs will be able to connect the outside world (and also get traffic inside). They don't necessarily have to to run traffic between two different IPs if that matters.

I'm able to enable each interface on its own, however when starting another interface, things stops working - I suspect the routing is the cause. Here's an example of two of the interfaces:

```
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:50:56:01:02:1a  
      inet addr:***.***.25.226  Bcast:***.***.25.231  Mask:255.255.255.248
      inet6 addr: fe80::250:56ff:fe01:21a/64 Scope:Link
      UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
      RX packets:7573 errors:0 dropped:96 overruns:0 frame:0
      TX packets:152 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
      RX bytes:454629 (454.6 KB)  TX bytes:21553 (21.5 KB)

eth1      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:50:56:01:02:1c  
      inet addr:***.***.25.227  Bcast:***.***.25.231  Mask:255.255.255.248
      inet6 addr: fe80::250:56ff:fe01:21c/64 Scope:Link
      UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
      RX packets:11461 errors:0 dropped:93 overruns:0 frame:0
      TX packets:1046 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
      RX bytes:5852814 (5.8 MB)  TX bytes:117633 (117.6 KB)
```

What should be the proper configuration for /etc/network/interfaces and proper routing?

Edit:

- network manager is disabled (service network-manager stop)
- I'm adding the first two stanzas from /etc/network/interfaces

  ```
  auto lo
  iface lo inet loopback

  auto eth0
  iface eth0 inet static
      address ***.***.25.226
      netmask ***.***.255.248
      gateway ***.***.25.225
      dns-nameservers 8.8.8.8

  auto eth1
  iface eth1 inet static
      address ***.***.25.227
      netmask ***.***.255.248
      gateway ***.***.25.225
      dns-nameservers 8.8.8.8
  ```

When I run ifup for both the route table (route -n) looks as follows:

```
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         ***.***.25.225  0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 eth0
***.***.25.224  0.0.0.0         255.255.255.248 U     0      0        0 eth0
***.***.25.224  0.0.0.0         255.255.255.248 U     0      0        0 eth1
169.254.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     1000   0        0 eth0
```

With the above setup, eth0 is able to ping outside (to www.google.com for instance) while eth1 can't.

Comment: Since you mention `/etc/network/interfaces` I understand you don't want to use Network Manager. Good. However, you haven't posted the stanzas you are trying to use, so it's difficult to guess what is going on. If two interfaces have IPs on the same subnet, only one of them can have a `gateway` declaration for the default gateway; you can have `up route add` stuff, though, and you can define nets or hosts which will be reached by one or another interface. Please post some more details about your situation (appropriately anonymized for the non relevant bytes, as you have already done) if you nee

Comment: @Dario Please see recent edit.